# Parse a Long number in Java

Tags: java, substring, long-integer, modulo

I want to parse a timestamp, a Long number like `14655**56648041**`. I want to create from this Long number two other Long numbers, One with the last four numbers `8041` and the second with `5664`. I can convert the number to String, use substring and then convert it again to Long, but I want to know if there is a cleaner way? I tried using `%` and `/` but didn't succeed.

Comment: Just FYI, you're gonna get tons of downvotes for "not enough research." I'll upvote, but that can only do so much.

Comment: Are the numbers you are pulling from this Long number 14655**56648041** always going to be between the *'s? I'm not sure it is entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: `n1 = num%10000;` `n2 = (num/10000)%10000;`

Comment: If performance isn't an issue (i.e. you're not doing that millions of times) I'd probably use string operations first. That seems cleaner and more flexible than operating on a single long number (e.g. if you always want to split in the middle and can have varying lengths or if the input is not merely a `long` but a _long_ number - that is a number which doesn't fit into `long` anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is. You can obtain the last four numbers by performing a modulo `10000` on the number:

```
long last4 = all%10000;
```

You can furthermore obtain the middle four digits by first dividing by `10000` and the again perform modulo:

```
long midl4 = (all/10000)%10000;
```

Or putting it all together:

```
long all = 1465556648041L;

long last4 = all%10000;
long midl4 = (all/10000)%10000;

System.out.println("all="+all);
System.out.println("last4="+last4);
System.out.println("midl4="+midl4);
```

[**jDoodle demo**](http://jdoodle.com/a/TV)

Answer (score 2):

The last 4 digits are `num % 1E4` and the four previous ones are `(num % 1E8 - (num % 1E4)) / 1E4`